# how to make the drop down option selected with database value using php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a select option in which values are populating from the database.
During updation I need to get that value selected.How can I do that?Please help.

Here is my code for select tag

```php
<select name="supplier_id" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="colFormLabelSm">
    <option value="0" selected="selected" disabled="disabled">
        Select supplier
    </option>
    <?php
    $supp_select = "SELECT supplier_id,supplier_name FROM supplier_details";
    $supp_query = mysqli_query($con, $supp_select);
    while ($supp_data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($supp_query)) {
        ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $supp_data['supplier_id'] ?>">
            <?php echo $supp_data['supplier_name']; ?>
        </option>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: you want to  out put what is selected or to show what is selected still in the option value?

Comment: just put `selected` attribute when item matched up in existing data with dropdown list.

Answer (score -1):

Put selected attribute on the option which is to be selected..Using if statement in option tag, check for which value is matching according to the value passed
E.g

```
<option <?php if(... ) echo "selected"; ?> value="value of db">
```